# How to list all categories in three divs dynamically based on the quatity of categories?

Tags: categories

I have 15 categories. I list this using `<div class="category_list"><ul><li><?php wp_list_categories();?></li></ul></div>`
Now it's listing all 15 categories into a single div which is category_list.

I am trying to print these categories 5 by 5 in three divs. like:

`<div class="category_list">first 5 categories here </div>`

`<div class="category_list">6th to 10th categories here </div>`

`<div class="category_list">11th to 15th categories here </div>`

Those divs are float next to each other I can do that using CSS.
But how can I achieve that HTML markup using PHP coding?

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not have a look at `get_categories`. This should give you more flexibility

Answer (score 4):

You can use [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function.

```
<?php
  $cats =  get_categories();
  $count = 15;  // Total Categorie
  $linetotal=round($count/3); ?>  // Part of Categorie

  <div class="category_list">
    <ul><?php
      $totalcount = 1;
      $totalpart = 1;
      foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
        <li><?php echo $cat->name; ?></li><?php
        if($totalcount % $linetotal == 0 && $totalpart < 3) { 
          echo '</ul></div><div class="category_list"><ul>';
              $totalpart++;
        }
        $totalcount++;
      endforeach;?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for this. It's working fine if total category is 15. I'm trying to assign value to $count based on the number of categories. `<? $date_arch = wp_get_archives('echo=0'); $date_arch = explode( '<li>' , $date_arch ); $date_arch_count = count($date_arch); echo $date_arch_count;?>` is echoing total number of categories. But `<? $cats =  get_categories('echo=0'); $cats =  expload( '<li>', $cats); $cats_count = count($cats); echo $cats_count; ?>`says **Call to undefined function expload()** if we can get this value like `$cats_count` we can assign value to `$cats`.any idea?

Answer (score 1):

wp_list_categories() is default wordpress function to show categories.
It itself append the html with category items and print it accordingly.

Now if you want to show categories in 3 div grid you need to print it with your custom code.
First load all the terms of category type then

```
    $terms=get_terms( 'categories', array('orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false,'depth' => 3));
```

echo "<pre>";
print_r($terms);
echo "</pre>";
die;

It will display you category array. Now you can traverse this array to print it in any format.

Or you can use the same function to print  category 3 times in all the3 three divs.Just specify the particular ids (excluding those 10 that you don't want)

```
wp_list_categories('show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&title_li=0&exclude=1, 16, 30, 31, 32, 78, 80, 9');
```

Here enter those 10 category ids that you want the first div then exclude other 10 that you don't want in the second div, same for the 3rd div